# How can I concatenate only some fields with a hyphen?

Tags: perl, concatenation

Input:

```
F1  F2         F3         F4       F5        F6  

4   ABCDEF1234 1111111111 20090101 00:00:00  XYZ 123
```

Output:

```
4   ABCDEF1234 1111111111 20090101-00:00:00  XYZ 123
```

F represents fields. F4 and F5 are date fields which needs to be concatenated with a hyphen. Is there a quick Perl script that does this?

Answer (score 4):

```
s/(\d{8})\s+(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})/$1-$2/
```

Comment: Interestingly different interpretation of the question.  Of course, it could also be F[0]..$F[5] that was intended, as with the autosplit mode.

Comment: @chaos: I was about to post the same. :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
printf("%-4s%s %s %s-%s  %s\n", $F1, $F2, $F3, $F4, $F5, $F6);
```

This answer assumes that the fields are already split up into variables $F1 .. $F6.  If the data is a single string, then the regex answer is more nearly appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

The input looks kind of fixed-width-y, that suggests `pack` and `unpack`.

```
my @F = unpack( 'A4 A11 A11 A19 A7', $input_line );
$F[3] =~ s/\d\K\s+/-/; # Use lookaround (?<=\d) if \K is not available
my $line = pack( 'A4 A11 A11 A19 A7', @F );
```

Then again, if it's fixed enough, you can just go:

```
substr( $input_line, 34, 1, '-' );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "4   ABCDEF1234 1111111111 20090101 00:00:00  XYZ 123";
@s = split /\s/,$str;
$s[5] = join("-",$s[5],$s[6]);
splice(@s,6,1);
print join(" ",@s);
```

Answer (score 1):

If format is with fixed column width:

```
perl -pe'substr$_,34,1,"-"'
```

Otherwise something like:

```
perl -ane'printf"%-4s%s %s %s-%s  %s\n",@F'
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly in command line:

```
$ perl -n -e '@fields = split; printf "%s %s %s %s-%s %s %s\n", $fields[0], $fields[1], $fields[2], $fields[3], $fields[4], $fields[5]' input.txt > output.txt
```

Remember that this is equivalent to put:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
while (<>) {
  @fields = split;
  printf "%s %s %s %s-%s %s %s\n", $fields[0], $fields[1], $fields[2], $fields[3], $fields[4], $fields[5];
}
```